# How do i make the guesses go down by one in hangman

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried to make the guesses go down by one if the word they clicked on dont match the word. but every time i try to do it, it either makes the guesses go down one but then it will also go down when the word matches. and if i try changing the code the guesses will go down by how many words there are left. Like this one

```
function wordChecker(cell) {

    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] === cell.innerHTML) {

            answerArray[i] = cell.innerHTML
            answer.innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ")
            remainingLetters--
            checkWin()
            console.log(remainingLetters);
            console.log(answerArray);
            break;

        } else {
            guesses.innerHTML--
            console.log(guesses);
        }
    }

}
```

i thought it could be because of the for loop and even though i make an if outside of the for loop i doesnt work properly.

Comment: You can't increment an innerHTML like that `guesses.innerHTML--` - try `guesses.innerHTML = Number(guesses.innerHTML)-1`

Comment: `innnerHTML` returns a string. You can't use arithmetic operations (such as `--`) on strings. We're also not seeing enough of the code (we don't know what `word`, `remainingLetters` or `guesses` are; nor do we know what your HTML markup looks like). Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve], making sure it produces the exact error/bug you're seeing.

Comment: @Kinglish it still doesnt work right. even though when i use guesses.innerHTML-- or the one you suggested it still goes down by how many words there are left

Comment: @tao  i'll try to do it but where do i put it

Comment: @tao i made a https://jsfiddle.net/adtcfy8g/2/ if you want to try it there.  just make the screen a bit bigger so you can press the buttons. and the word is logged in console

Comment: You're looking for `guesses.innerHTML = '' + (Number(guesses.innerHTML) - 1);`. That being said, I'm not going to fix it for you; there are way too many things wrong with it, with both CSS and JS. At the same time, I really admire you for putting it all together considering how little you know about the basics. Keep at it, you're getting there.

Comment: @tao it still doesn't work with what you said

Comment: It should. Are you sure you're getting there (e.g: the code executes everything up to that line and that code is run)? Have you tried logging? Do you see any errros?

Comment: Never use *"it doesn't work"* when coding. Technically, It doesn't mean anything, because it can mean anything. It's practically useless and can only create confusion. Be very specific about what you do to create an error, what you expect and what's actually happening. When you're able to describe all of those without anyone misunderstanding, you're in a good place.

Comment: See it decreasing [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wj3mfx4g/). Have a look at the condition. Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). And here's a [bonus](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/pr6ztqgj/).

Comment: @tao oh i didn't know about the include function. but what about the answerArray[i] now. before it looped through the array with the for loop but now that it is changed with includes is it a way to display the letter to the html with that

Comment: Separate the condition (which decides if the counter should go down) from the loop, which updates the displayed letters. Put the for in a separate function. If you combine them, you'll decrease the counter for each letter. You don't want that.

Comment: @tao sorry i didnt quite understand that. but did you mean to make a new funtcion with the for loop and then call it in the first include condition?

Comment: @tao thank you for your help i made it work. you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/31xmjkrw/3/ .  i created a new function with for loop and called it in the first condition of include. i think thats what you wanted me to do

Comment: Since you made it work, it sounds like it's what *you* wanted to do. Right?

Comment: @tao YES, now i will just add the hangman person or whatever you call it and fix some css stuff. i think it will go smoothly